# Tensorflow: Understanding tf.contrib.layers.instance_norm graph

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I'm trying to understand `tf.contrib.layers.instance_norm` graph:

according to this graph:

```
x = gamma * (x + x_mean) / x_std - beta
```

but it should be

```
x = gamma * (x - x_mean) / x_std + beta
```

I'm missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, it's `x = gamma * (x - x_mean) / x_std + beta` as it should be because in `Sub` order is `beta - 'Sub op input'`.